# Как создать привязку к объекту, определённому в другом пространстве имён?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

В ходе разработки графического интерфейса на WPF, использующего одну библиотеку классов, столкнулся с проблемой: не понимаю как привязать объект Configuration как статический ресурс к элементам графического интерфейса.
Написал:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Configuration x:Key="config"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Но такое не компилируется, хотя Configuration прекрасно виден из кода на C#, а вот в разметке - нет.
Попытался описать пространство имён `xmlns:lib` по аналогии с `xmlns:local`

```
<Window x:Class="GUI.MainWindow"
    <…>
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GUI"
    xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:ClassLibrary">
```

Не смотря на это, высвечивается две ошибки:

- `XDG0008: The name "Configuration" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:ClassLibrary".`
- `XLS0414: The type 'lib:Configuration' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.`

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно просто указать название сборки, в которой определено пространство имён, вот так:

```
xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:ClassLibrary;assembly=ClassLibrary"
```

После этого всё должно заработать.

*Источник: Microsoft ([XAML Namespaces and Namespace Mapping for WPF XAML](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml))*